# $(document).ready works when inserted into _Layout.cshtml :: doesn't work when inserted into Index.cshtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I know if it was a snake it would have bit me. But I can't see why it works in _Layout header file, but not in specific Index page where I need it. I can't see having this code in every page that uses the _Layout.cshtml.

Here is jQuery code that works IF in _Layout. I cut and paste it into Index.cshtml and it won't even fire an alert. What it is expected to do: It clears an input if the other input changes (can only search by either name or ID).

not represented here are the javascript surrounding tags.
I tried just an alert with all other code turned off.
For some reason the javascript tag is not firing.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    alert('doc ready in _layout just fired');

            $('#SearchString').on('input', function () {
                $('#SearchID').val('');
            });

            $('#SearchID').on('input', function () {
                $('#SearchString').val('');
            });
});
```

This doesn't work in Index.cshtml wherever it is placed:

```
<script type="text/javacript">
alert('code in Index test');
</script>
```

======================================

So, this just in:
I put the jQuery code needed for single page in a ".js" file with nothing in there but the code.
Then I referenced this file at the top of my Index.cshtml and it works:

```
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/search.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now, this is a nice workaround that gives some degree of separation for those that like that, but I hate saying this is the answer to why Index.cshtml was bypassing the javacript tags with jQuery code in them. So I'm not answering my question, just saying so it might help someone else who has pulled out almost all their hair. . . .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using razor engine? This is what I usually have...

In _layout.chstml

```
<head>
    @RenderSection("Head", false)
</head>
```

and then in your view

```
@section Head {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // your code goes here
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Woo hoo! It works. Thank you very much.
Some high jingo must be happening that cancels it out.

Comment: If you are using ASP.NET MVC 4, @RenderSection("scripts", required: false) will be at the bottom of your _Layout.cshtml page after the footer. That is opposed to @RenderSection("Head", false) being in the head. It is recommended that script be included at the bottom of your pages. https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom