# What the preferred way to add view-specific JavaScript to an Asp.Net Core 2 MVC application?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have JavaScript that I'd like to add to a single Razor view (`CSHTML`), which should be associated with an `input` that filters a `TABLE`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // added for testing
    alert('ready');

    (function ($) {

        $('#filter').keyup(function () {

            var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
            $('.searchable tr').hide();
            $('.searchable tr').filter(function () {
                return rex.test($(this).text());
            }).show();

        })

    }(jQuery));

});
```

At the moment, the code is contained in a `SCRIPT` tag located at the bottom of the view.

When the page loads, the alert never fires.

If I wrap the `SCRIPT`:

```
@section Head {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // your code goes here
        });
    </script>
}
```

this error is produced:

> InvalidOperationException: The following sections have been defined
>   but have not been rendered by the page at
>   '/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml': 'Head'. To ignore an unrendered
>   section call IgnoreSection("sectionName").

What the preferred way to add view-specific JavaScript to an Asp.Net Core 2 MVC application?

relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24895364/134367

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45796556/the-following-sections-have-been-defined-but-have-not-been-rendered-for-the-layo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page “~/Views/Shared/\_Layout.cshtml”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45796556/the-following-sections-have-been-defined-but-have-not-been-rendered-for-the-layo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer.

I wrapped my `JAVASCRIPT` in a `@section Scripts` block:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        alert('ready');

        (function ($) {

            $('#filter').keyup(function () {

                var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
                $('.searchable tr').hide();
                $('.searchable tr').filter(function () {
                    return rex.test($(this).text());
                }).show();

            })

        }(jQuery));

    });
    </script>
}
```

This appears to be called by `@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)` in the _Layout.cshtml.

Once I did this and reloaded the page, the alert fired and the remainder of the code worked as expected.